# why download a file dont work kept in model pop up?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am opening some Panel having a some code like this

```
 <td rowspan="2">
                        <br />
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnl" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkYurLevel" runat="server" ForeColor="#009999" Text="What are my next steps?"
                                    Font-Size="Medium" OnClick="lnkYurLevel_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </td>

 protected void lnkYurLevel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lblFileName.Text != "")
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath(@"~\downloads\" + lblFileName.Text);
            System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
            if (file.Exists)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
                Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
            }
        }

    }
```

and on button click i am opening a file that is to be download but that download don't appear, as it was working when not kept in panel that is to be open through model pop up.
Now when it is placed in a panel that is to be open through model pop up. it doesn't work.
What is the reason?

Comment: The file gets created but the save dialog never appears on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An action inside the `UpdatePanel` won't change the whole `Response`, just a part of the page. So you cannot expect `Response.Write` to work. The alternative is to make the button force a full `PostBack`

---

Add a `PostBackTrigger` to the `asp:Button` like this

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkYurLevel" />
</Triggers>
```

or if you want to do that in code-behind, do this.

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(lnkYurLevel);
```

Comment: Yes, it does work, but my question is whay i had to define trigger while, when i did not define trigger the break point was getting hit.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: the first line explains the reason in simple terms. does it not?

Comment: @Aristos: Sorry. I thtought it was somebody just click happy :)

Answer (score 2):

The UpdatePanel that you use, expect very specific data (actually wait a struct with the result) from the post back, and this data are used on javascript to update his content. What you do is to totally break that data and you still expect to work. This can not work and you get a javascript error from the page, from the updatepanel. With other words the update panel gets some data from you that did not know what to do with them.

Comment: so how to make it correct, The file gets created but the save dialog never appears on the client.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet yes, because of the UpdatePanel that you have warp it.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet I like to say that way is also not good practice, is an easy solution, but not the correct solution for an asp.net page. Better solution is to use a handle to send the file and you just make the link to this handle with the correct url parametres.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet And also this `Response.Write("This file does not exist.");` do you ever have see whats and where its going to write it ? make a test to see. Maybe at the end of the page, maybe at the top... but it will be un-readable, except if your page is a empty white.